# Pass an Armadillo function to a user defined function

Tags: c++, templates, armadillo

Is it possible to pass an Armadillo function to an arbitrary function in an **elegant** manner? Specifically, I want to be able to pass arma::tanh to my neural network so that it calculates the network output, i.e. something similar to this:

```
arma::mat y = network.ForwardPropagate(x, arma::tanh);
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to use a function of your choice on Armadillo matrices, through the [.transform()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#transform) member function.

Example using C++11:

```
mat A(100,100,fill::randu);

A.transform( [](double val) { return tanh(val); } );
```